# Need help configuring apache with 3 different hostnames that support wildcard subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, hosting, subdomain, virtualization, host

I have a single physical server. I need to set it up so i can have 3 different domains on it. Each one of these domains needs to be able to support wildcard sub-domains. (*.example.com,*.example2.com,*.example3.com) I can purchase two more ips if this will make things easier.

The current setup is as follows

www.example.com => default vhost

devel.example.com => development server this is the only server that currently accepts *.example.com

staging.example.com => only works via staging.example.com

essentially i need all of these different to accept a wild card subdomain which i why i believe i need separate domain names for each.

What is the best way to get this all setup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the wildcard domain up via DNS.  For each domain that will be different, however, you will need to create a subdomain for it via DNS.  Setup the Apache configuration using the `ServerAlias` and `ServerName` for your main subdomain and `ServerAlias` for your subdomains:

```
<VirtualHost IP:80>
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost IP:80>
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    ServerAlias devel.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost IP:80>
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    ServerAlias staging.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

You could use .htaccess to do the same thing I believe, but I like doing it this way better - personal preference.

Comment: in this configuration i would need a separate ip for each... correct?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Nope, you can use `NameVirtualHost IPADDRESS:80` above your VirtualHosts, and then use that IP address in your `VirtualHost IPADDRESS:80` stanza.

Comment: So that it is easier to read, I created a private pastie for you - here's what part of it would look like: http://pastie.org/private/x5uxpvgfnfdrffypkrr71g

Comment: im going to test this out tomorrow i will be sure to post back with my results.. thanks again

Comment: No problem! Let us know if you run into any snags.