# Configuring Apache virtual hosts on the same domain

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm having some problems configuring virtual hosts on Apache. I want to define two different subdomains aaa.example.com and bbb.example.com, both using the same IP address (both DNS records have already been defined). I'm using apache v2.2.15 on CentOS 6.4.

This is the configuration I've created in httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName aaa.example.com
   ServerAlias example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   Redirect / https://aaa.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAlias bbb.example.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bbb
   Redirect / https://bbb.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

However, the problem I've found is that if I try to access to bbb.example.com using a browser, I get the pages from aaa.example.com, but the url is rewritten as bbb.example.com. I've tried to define different ServerAlias directives, and specifying the IP address in both the NameVirtualHost and VirtualHosts directives, but without success.

I've looked into this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/173958/need-help-configuring-apache-with-3-different-hostnames-that-support-wildcard-su), but it didn't work for me.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**

**CHANGES AFTER GUIDO VACARELLA'S SUGGESTIONS**

I've done some modifications after Guido Vaccarella's suggestions:

The current config, which is partially working, is the following:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName aaa.example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerAlias example.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName bbb.example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/bbb"
ServerAlias bbb.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This config works for both domains. However, I need that all the http traffic is redirected to https (note that I've omitted the redirects), and that's what's not working.

Is there any way to redirect all the http traffic to https? I've tried to replicate the same config for port 443, but it does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using only the ServerName directive in both virtualhosts. I see also a redirect to https... probably you need also virtualhosts on 443 port.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: Guido, I did some changes, and it's partially working. Please refer to the comment I've added (I needed to add some code)

Comment: Sorry, I see no difference. What have you added?

Comment: Have you added the NameVirtualHost *:443 clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache .htaccess files can do the dirty work of changing http to https...

Here is an example I found that checks both with and without www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Try posting this data into the <Directory> section of your config file instead of .htaccess if you want it to be for every page.

Comment: Glad we could help -- there are many ways to skin a cat ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jeff, your suggestions works. Anyway, I could make it work (in a more complicated way):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName aaa.example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
ServerAlias example.com
Redirect / https://aaa.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName bbb.example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/bbb"
ServerAlias bbb.example.com
Redirect / https://bbb.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apacheaaa.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apacheaaa.key
ServerName aaa.example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apachebbb.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/apachebbb.key
ServerName bbb.example.com
DocumentRoot "/var/www/bbb"
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks Guido and Jeff for your help.